# AppleScript to copy two image from a folder and paste into outlook mail body

Tags: ios, macos, applescript, automator

I'm new to apple scripting and I'm trying to copy two image from a folder and paste into outlook mail body, below is the code I have written so far to compose mail and I need help in pasting two images in the mail body.

I don't want it to be an attachment file, image needs to be pasted in mail body itself.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
activate
set theSubject to "Subject" 
set theContent to "This is my content"
set theAttachmentFile to "XXXXX" 
set sendToAddress to "abc"
set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent} -> I'm missing something here
with properties {file:theAttachmentFile} 
open msg
end tell
```

Comment: Think about how you would do this in real life. You would have to _open_ the image file with some app, such as Preview, and say Edit > Copy. Then you would switch to the Outlook edit window and say Edit > Paste. Now do that using AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

So in case if someone is struggling with this same question. I would like to answer what I implemented.

Compose your mail body content in html format and use img tag for inserting images in your mail body.